# How to correctly reinstall network-manager

Tags: wireless, networking

I tried to install connman and it didn't work, so I removed it. Then I tried to      sudo apt-get install network-manager network-manager-gnome` and that obviously didn't work so I found the correct .deb packages and installed them. Ethernet now works, but wireless doesn't. Did I do something wrong? Whenever I press my hardware wireless switch it doesn't react. The applet tells me that wireless is disabled by a hardware switch, but my only hardware switch doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was on airport mode by default, I just had to switch it. [[facepalm]]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude reinstall network-manager*
```

Comment: I don't think that you need aptitude to re-install something, but I'm not sure. Anyway, you gave me the idea to "sudo apt-get install network-manager*". Let's hope that works :)

Comment: Okay, neither works. Sigh. Now it just says "wireless is disabled by a hardware switch".